# Flatten the query results produced by OUTPUT into plain text using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, text

I use the `OUTPUT` clause in my `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements to protocol the changes made to the database by my script. For logging purposes I would like to flatten the output of the `OUTPUT` clause into a single plain text value that I could insert into a a single cell of my debugging audit table.

The only solution I made up my mind with is to manually concatenate all output fields, but since some of them can be `NULL` I also have to check for that before concatenation and the final script looks ugly.

Is there any simpler and more elegant way to flatten the output into plain text, similar to how it is done with XML clause `FOR XML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.[trg_IOIU_test]
   ON dbo.[vw_test]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON

    DECLARE
        @DocumentUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @Date DATETIME

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
        SELECT DocumentUID, [Date]
        FROM INSERTED

    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DocumentUID, @Date

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        DECLARE 
              @BeforeChange NVARCHAR(MAX)
            , @AfterChange NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @BeforeChange = (
            SELECT * 
            FROM DELETED 
            WHERE [DocumentUID] = @DocumentUID FOR XML RAW, ROOT
        )
        SET @AfterChange = (
            SELECT * 
            FROM INSERTED 
            WHERE [DocumentUID] = @DocumentUID FOR XML RAW, ROOT
        )

        -- insert/update statement

        EXEC dbo.[AddLog]
                @DocumentUID = @DocumentUID,
                @BeforeChange = @BeforeChange,
                @AfterChange = @AfterChange

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DocumentUID, @Date
    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

END
```